# Somar value de um checkbox Instantaneamente

Tags: php, javascript

Como  não tenho muito conhecimento de javascript gostaria de uma ajuda de como posso fazer esse script de calculo,  gostaria que ao clicar em cada checkbox automaticamente me mostre o resultado na tela somando todas as marcadas
e uma subtração de uma variavel

```
 <?
 $variavel = 100,00
 ?>

 <input type="" checked="" value="20,00"  />
 <input type="" checked="" value="20,00"  />
 <input type="" checked="" value="20,00"  />
 <input type="" checked="" value="20,00"  />

 <div id='resultado_soma'><?echo $total?></div>  <!--Resultado da soma dos 
 checkbox-->
 <div id='resultado_soma_menos_variavel'><?echo $total_geral?></div>  <!-- 
 Resultado Pegando      
 a Variavel - Resultado checkbox -->
```

Comment: Amigo, Você precisa nomear o nome dos input's, Para que possam serem atribuídos a funções em javascript, Se todos não tiverem ID's atribuídas, Não é possível fazer a soma. Por exemplo: <input type="" checked="" value="20,00" id="val1" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja esse código se ajuda vc:

```
<? 
$variavel = 100;
?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="soma" checked="checked" value="20" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="soma" value="20" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="soma" value="20" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="soma" value="20" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="soma" value="20" />
    <label>Resultado subtraindo</label>
    <input id='resultado' type="text" value='20' />
    <label>Resultado sem subtrair</label>
     <input id='resultado_sem_subtratir' type="text" value='20' />
    </form>

    <script>
    function somartotal() {
    var resultado = $("input:checked");
    var i=0;
    var total = 0;
    for (i=0;i<resultado.length;i++)
    {
    total = total+parseInt(resultado[i].value);

    }
     total_subtraindo = total - <?php echo $variavel;?>
     $("#resultado").val("R$ " + total_subtraindo.toFixed(2).replace('.',','));
  $("#resultado_sem_subtratir").val("R$ " + total.toFixed(2).replace('.',','));


    }

    somartotal();
    $(":checkbox").click(somartotal);

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Ola Isso mesmo só falou o resultado diminuir a $variavel  -  total  = xxx

Comment: Ola Amigo esse ultimo não funcionou e acho que voce não entendeu. seriam duas saidas,  uma com o somatorio das checkbox e outra pegando a variavel e subitraindo o valor do somatório somatorio das checkbox.

Comment: realmente não funfou pq nao fechei o php '?>'. Veja agora, fiz conforme o que pediu com duas opções uma mostrando subtraindo e outra não.

Comment: Isso mesmo.Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Vamos lá, a primeira coisa que modifiquei no seu código foram os inputs para facilitar o resultado veja:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="" value="20.00"  />
<input type="checkbox" checked="" value="20.00"  />
<input type="checkbox" checked="" value="20.00"  />
<input type="checkbox" checked="" value="20.00"  />
```

Adicionei o type para checkbox e alterei a virgula para ponto

Agora para você utilizar as variáveis em PHP como $variavel, $total e $total_geral será necessário você salvar os dados após cada alteração nos checkbox, você pode utilizar ajax para isso.

```
<?
 $variavel = 100,00
 ?>
<input type="checkbox" checked="" value="20.00"  />
<input type="checkbox" checked="" value="20.00"  />
<input type="checkbox" checked="" value="20.00"  />
<input type="checkbox" checked="" value="20.00"  />
<div id='resultado_soma'><?echo $total?></div>  <!--Resultado da soma dos checkbox-->
<div id='resultado_soma_menos_variavel'><?echo $total_geral?></div>
<!-- Resultado Pegando a Variavel - Resultado checkbox -->
```

Agora o javascript para tudo isso funcionar

```
(function() {
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado_soma');
var total = 100.00;

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function() {
        if (this.checked === false) {
            total = total - this.value;
        } else {
            total = total + parseFloat(this.value);
        }

        resultado.innerHTML = total;
    }
}})();
```

Você pode ver o código completo aqui também : https://jsfiddle.net/kcnhr66w/1/

Comment: Nesse script como posso fazer que ao clicarmos alem da soma mostrar o names e os values dos checkbox marcados

Comment: os names você quer dizer o atributo name do input ?

Comment: sim o name="" e o value=""

Comment: modelo http://i.stack.imgur.com/E0VQG.jpg

Comment: Não sei se é exatamente isso que você precisa mas aqui vai um novo exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/g055ndgq/4/

Comment: não não... só mostrar c1 20.00, c2 20.00...  se clicados