# Somar campos Checkbox no Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como Não tenho conhecimento de javascript gostaria de uma ajudinha de como posso fazer esse script a baixo funcionar dentro de um while e fazer com que some também as casas decimais fora do loop ele funciona mais dentro da bug
como corrigir isso

```
     while ($row = $retorno->fetch_assoc()) {   } // O codigo ficaria aqui dentro
```

```js
$(function(){
 total = document.getElementById('total');
 $(document.getElementsByName('choice')).bind('click',function(){
  var valTotal = parseInt(total.value),valInput = parseInt(this.value),novoTotal=0;
  total.value = (this.checked) ? ( valTotal + valInput ) : ( valTotal - valInput ) ;
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="listForm" id="listForm">
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,55" />2,55<br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,00" />2,00<br/>
 <input type="text" size="2" name="total" id="total" value="100,00"/>
</form>
```

Comment: agora que vi, essa pergunta já tem resposta  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83280/somar-value-de-um-checkbox-instantaneamente

Comment: Essa outra resposta não me soluciona a questão do loop

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que assim funcione do modo desejado, bastando inserir o código abaixo dentro do `while.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".valores").change(function() {
        var total = 100.00;
        total += $('input[class="valores"]:checked').get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
            return tot + Number(el.value);
        }, 0);
        $('#total').val(total);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="valores" name="choice" value="2.55" />2,55<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="valores" name="choice" value="2.00" />2,00<br/>

<br><br>Resultado<input type="text" size="2" name="total" id="total" value="100,00"/>
```

Comment: Ola aMIgo Não funciona em loop tambem se clicar na linha de baixo altera o valor de cima

Answer (score 1):

> As linguagens de programação utilizam sistema de numeração internacional, não existe vírgulas é ponto para poder fazer operações matemáticas

Sem fugir do seu código, apenas formatando os números para poder fazer operações matemáticas.

```js
$(function(){
 total = document.getElementById('total');
 $(document.getElementsByName('choice')).bind('click',function(){
 
  var valTotal = total.value;
  
  valTotal = parseFloat(valTotal.replace(',','.'));
  
  var valInput = (this.value);
  
  valInput = parseFloat(valInput.replace(',','.'));
  
  var novoTotal=0;
  total.value = (this.checked) ? parseFloat(( valTotal + valInput )) : parseFloat(( valTotal - valInput )) ;
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form name="listForm" id="listForm">
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,55" />2,55<br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,00" />2,00<br/>
 <input type="text" size="6" name="total" id="total" value="100,00"/>
</form>
```

Caso queira que o total tenha sempre 2 casas decimais em  `total.value` use a função   [**toFixed**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)

```js
$(function(){
 total = document.getElementById('total');
 $(document.getElementsByName('choice')).bind('click',function(){
 
  var valTotal = total.value;
  
  valTotal = parseFloat(valTotal.replace(',','.'));
  
  var valInput = (this.value);
  
  valInput = parseFloat(valInput.replace(',','.'));
  
  var novoTotal=0;
  total.value = (this.checked) ? parseFloat(( valTotal + valInput )).toFixed(2) : parseFloat(( valTotal - valInput )).toFixed(2) ;
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form name="listForm" id="listForm">
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,55" />2,55<br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,45" />2,45<br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,50" />2,50<br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,00" />2,00<br/>
 <input type="text" size="4" name="total" id="total" value="100,00"/>
</form>
```

Para voltar a apresentar o total com vírgula.

```js
$(function() {
  total = document.getElementById('total');
  $(document.getElementsByName('choice')).bind('click', function() {

    var valTotal = total.value;

    valTotal = parseFloat(valTotal.replace(',', '.'));

    var valInput = (this.value);

    valInput = parseFloat(valInput.replace(',', '.'));

    var novoTotal = 0;
    var value = (this.checked) ? parseFloat((valTotal + valInput)).toFixed(2) : parseFloat((valTotal - valInput)).toFixed(2);
    total.value = value.replace('.', ',');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form name="listForm" id="listForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,55" />2,55<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,45" />2,45<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,50" />2,50<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,00" />2,00<br/>
  <input type="text" size="4" name="total" id="total" value="100,00" />
</form>
```

DOCS:

[replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

[parseFloat](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)

Comment: ola amigo Não funciona em loop também. se clicar na linha de baixo altera o valor de cima

Comment: @Fabio Henrique Não entendi o porque do script dentro do loop. Pensei que o problema fosse somente somar os decimais

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor na pergunta a finalidade do script dentro do while?

Comment: COMO FAÇO NESSE CÓDIGO PARA PEGAR EM VEZ DO VALUE O ALT POR EXEMPLO?